# Getting List of All Instructor Enrollments

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I've been using `/d2l/api/lp/1.4/enrollments/myenrollments/` to get a list of enrollments for the current user. Now, I want to just get the enrollments where the user is in an instructor role. So, I'm trying to use:

```
/d2l/api/lp/1.4/enrollments/users/{userId}/orgUnits/?roleId=105
```

When I use that, I get an empty list of Items back, with or without the roleId specified.

My expectation is that just calling it without the roleId would return the same list as `/d2l/api/lp/1.4/enrollments/myenrollments/`. But, I always get an empty list, except when I log in as a system administrator. Only in that case do I get anything back.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The various `my*` API calls specifically exist to provide end users to fetch back details about the system that they should know, but segregated from information they shouldn't (that's available through the more general routes for a particular area). Enrollments is a good example of this. And end-user should be able to see their own enrollments, but they should not have generalized access to enrollment records. In particular, the D2L system treats the D2L user role belonging to an enrollment as fairly privileged information, and a side effect of this is that it's not generally visible to end users.

One way that applications and services can cope with achieving goals that the end-user cannot themselves perform is to have set up a "service account" that the app can use to make calls of an administrative nature, to fetch back data that they can use in the business logic around presenting information to end users. In this particular case, you could, for example use the service account to make calls about a user's enrollments, and then present the user with logic that could filter the list of their enrollments by "these are the student ones, and these are the ones where you're a teacher, and a tutor, and so forth".

But you'd also need to carefully consider the implications of this type of activity in balance against the intentions of the client LMS's policies and administration. Even this level of information may be giving away too much to end users, in the eyes of a client LMS administrator.

Using a service account to let an app make administrative level calls must always be done with great care around the issue of information/functional leakage to end users.